# How to pass textarea value to controller action on the click of a button in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net application I have a textarea which takes the reviews of the user as input.

```
<div>
  <textarea name="mytext" id="mytext"></textarea>
</div>
```

This textarea can be accessed using the id.

I have next defined a button (image button) as follows:

```
<a class="btn btn-success">Leave a Review</a>
```

I would like to pass the value of the textarea to a controller action when the Leave a Review button is clicked.

Currently I redirect to a controller action as follows:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" onclick="localtion.href='@Url.Action("ControllerAction", "ControllerName", new { // pass data here })'">Leave a Review</a>
```

How can this be achieved, any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: create a form, then add textarea inside the form, set a "name" attribute to your textarea and use that name to access its contents in your controller

Comment: ^ or make an AJAX request on click of the `a` element

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery

```
     <div>
         <textarea name="mytext" id="mytext"></textarea>
     </div>
     <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction">Leave a Review</a>

     function myFunction(){
     var myText =$('#mytext').val();
     var number = parseInt(@ViewBag.Number); //Accessing the number from the ViewBag
     alert("Number is: " + number);
     var model = @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.FooObj); //Accessing the Json Object from ViewBag
     alert("Text is: " + model.Text);
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ControllerAction", "ControllerName", new { someParam = "myText", viewbagNum = number ,viewbagModelText =  model.Text})'
    }
```

Comment: Your method seems to work well, however, unfortunately I have to pass one more value which is set inside the ViewBag and I think cannot be accessed in the jquery code.

Comment: @SpiderMan sure you can accesss the value from ViewBag. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter like :

```
 <textarea name="mytext" id="mytext"></textarea>
 <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="LeaveReviewFunc()">Leave a Review</a>

  function LeaveReviewFunc() {
      var textareadata = $("#mytext").val();
      window.localtion.href='@Url.Action("ControllerAction", "ControllerName", new { text : textareadata  })';
  }
```

And in action:

```
public ActionResult ControllerAction(string text) {
     //enter code here
}
```

Comment: This won't work, as I need to get the value of the text when the button is pressed. This code would get the value when the page was loaded.

Comment: onclick="LeaveReviewFunc()"   It will fire on click of Leave a Review button

Comment: Yeah this works, however,  using variable textareadata inside the Url.Action method results in the error:

Comment: Saying, the name textareadata does not exist in the current context. @danish443

Comment: Try `window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ControllerAction", "ControllerName")' + '?text=' + textareadata;`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to controller via two ways.
 1. Create a form put this textarea into the form tag.
 2. Call a Js Method on click of button.In this Js mehtod make a ajax request.